# MVC3 Razor Table loading outside of Span/Div/P

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having a problem where I try to render a `<table>` inside of parent container, but MVC3 Razor always renders the  outside of the container tag.  This causes problems when trying to control the outside parent container via Javascript.

Razor Example:

```
<span id="mySpan">
 @Html.Action("Table1", "GetMyTable")
</span>
```

HTML that is output:

```
 <span id="mySpan"></span>  
 <table>
  <thead><tr><th>Header</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Bar</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

No matter which parent container I try to stick the table into, a div, span, p, the table always renders OUTSIDE the container's tags!  Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?  How should I code the Razor syntax to properly add the table inside those tags?

Comment: how are you viewing the output? I would be willing to bet you are seeing a browser's "corrected" view of HTML5, where a span tag would be automatically ended by including something inside it that is invalid (such as a table tag). Meaning you are viewing the effective output - not the literal output, which should not be changed from the (invalid) output you expect.

Comment: That is: I have never seen Razor attempt to change your literal output in this way, so I ak much more apt to think this is a case of the browser "fixing" your HTML.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - OK, didn't realize that Table was invalid within a div or span.  To answer your question, I was viewing the HTML via Firebug in Firefox.  Is there any way to get a table inside a div or other html parent for javascript control purposes?

Comment: it should go in a div just fine. it's invalid in a span or p, though. View using viee source straight from the browser, too; Firebug does exactly what I noted. (which is good to see in this case, too; css won't apply how you think it should if your html is invalid)

Comment: looks like I am wrong; it's invalid inside a div in HTML5, too. Does your site need to be html5? Could you do XHtml1.1? (where a table inside a div is valid)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - OK, I guess this isn't a Razor issue, but an HTML5 issue.  Yikes, what do people do when they need to control a block of HTML that includes a table?  It is something I used to do constantly in the 'old days'.  You know, like the day before yesterday.

Comment: Well, the table is its own block, so it shouldn't need another one. You could also try a section tag, instead of a div. HTML5 aims for much more semantic-correctness; and nesting blocks isn't very semantic. div is pretty much a second class citizen in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are viewing the output in Firebug, what is happening is you are seeing an "effective" view of the html, after the browser engine has parsed it.
in HTML5, many tags do not need to be explicitly closed. If you include a tag "inside" another that is invalid (like a table inside a span), the browser assumes what you are doing is using an unclosed span tag, so it automatically closes it for you before starting the table tag.

The easiest fix here would be either not to "wrap" the table, or wrap it with something that HTML5 considers valid, such as a section tag.

Another option would be going back to XHTML1.1, where a table is valid inside a div (but not inside a span). Also, XHTML requires explicit closing tags, so this behavior would not show up there. (the same thing for XHTML5, though it's still invalid to wrap a table with a div in XHTML5)

Viewing the raw source would reveal that Razor is not axtually changing anything here; it is the browser. It is good to see this, though; so you know what the browser is expecting and how it's handling what you are sending it.